# hovers wordpress tema

Tags: html, css, hover

¿Como puedo hacer un hover que vaya a un link específico?

```
a:hover{
    color: #515151!important;
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Le puedes poner un `id` a ese enlace y usar el selector del id. También puedes hacer un selector mas especifico al que tienes ahora añadiendo al selector los padres y elementos ya que puede que sea un caso en el que sea una estructura única y no necesites el `id`.

Comment: Por cierto, te doy la bienvenida a SOes! Te recomiendo darte una vuelta por el [Tour de bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para ver como funciona el sitio y así de paso ¡ganar tu primera medalla!. También es importante leer [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para formular una pregunta de calidad y que esta sea bien recibida.

Comment: quiero que al pasar por encima del raton salga este color #515151 y que este puesto sin pasar el raton como en la captura

Comment: quiero que el azul que este puesto este puesto. y luego al pasar el raton quiero que este cone este codigo de color #515151

Answer (score 0):

muy fácil, si pones un id al link que quieras tocar  de la siguiente manera:

Código `html` (link)

```
<a id="nombreId" href="https://y lo que siga"></a>
```

y después enlazas con el código `CSS`

```
#nombreId:hover{
    color: #515151!important;
}
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105087/discussion-on-answer-by-david-robles-hovers-wordpress-tema).